# Regex to find multiple occurrence of string in column data for Oracle DB (11g)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In one of the column, I have JSON data stored in text format. Sample data looks like:

```
{
    "dummy_time": "2016-04-27T18:44:55+00:00",
    "timeout_data": "2016-04-29T16:22:35+00:00,2016-04-30T16:22:35+00:00,2016-05-29T16:22:35+00:00",
    "time_id": "T101",
    "time_desc": "bla bla bla"
}
```

I need to write SQL query to find out rows for whome this column has more than one date for key timeout_data. I am not that good with REGEX. I wrote simple query to find two occurences of dates in key timeout_data:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 f
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(f.data, '.+\"timeout_data\": \".+,.+\",\"time_id\".*')
AND ROWNUM<6;
```

And this query is running since ages. Table has around 35,000,000 rows.
I am not sure how to find more than one occurrences of dates in key timeout_data. Please let me know if you require more information.

Comment: Which version of Oracle? 12c supports JSON queries natively.

Comment: In your regex you check for two different strings, *timeout_data* and *time_id*, but in your text you talk about *more than one timeout_data*? What is correct?

Comment: He checks for existance of a comma in value of "timeout_data"

Comment: @dnoeth: I am checking for for 2 occurrences of dates in between fields timeout_data and time_id. I was just hoping that I would find an entry having 2 dates for key timeout_data. What I need is occurrences of date more than once, for key timeout_data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `instr()` will be faster.

```
SELECT 'test'
FROM  (SELECT '{
    "dummy_time": "2016-04-27T18:44:55+00:00",
    "timeout_data": "2016-04-29T16:22:35+00:00,2016-05-29T16:22:35+00:00",
    "time_id": "T101",
    "time_desc": "bla bla bla"
}' data FROM dual)
WHERE instr(data,',',instr(data,'"timeout_data"')) < instr(data,'"',instr(data,'"timeout_data"'),4);
```

You can test it on a subset of your data. Also, `instr(data,'"timeout_data"')` is used twice, maybe factoring it out will speed up the process.

Update: There seems to be problem with your REGEX - needs to have `.+` before `\"time_id\"`

Also - REGEX is not the limiting factor here. On my machine a loop of 100k SELECT .. FROM dual takes 4.3 seconds. With addition of REGEX it takes additional 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

1) Extract line with timeout_data

2) Count occurrence of pattern.

```
select REGEXP_COUNT(regexp_substr(json,'^.*timeout_data.*$', 1,1,'m'), '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T')
from ( 
select '{
    "dummy_time": "2016-04-27T18:44:55+00:00",
    "timeout_data": "2016-04-29T16:22:35+00:00,2016-04-30T16:22:35+00:00,2016-05-29T16:22:35+00:00",
    "time_id": "T101",
    "time_desc": "bla bla bla"
}' json from dual
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an ISO8601 formatted date using the regular expression:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}
```

If you wanted multiple comma-separated copies of it then you can use:

```
pattern(,pattern)+
```

(or remove the trailing `+` if you only want find exactly two matches)

So

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}(,\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})+
```

Which would make your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 f
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(f.data, '"timeout_data":\s*"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}(,\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})+"')
AND ROWNUM<6;
```

However, if you don't want to specifically match the dates and just want to test if there are multiple comma-separated values then you can use:

```
[^,"]+(,[^,"]+)+
```

*(Note: ensuring that the pattern does not match the closing double quote - otherwise the pattern might match beyond the end of the attribute.)*

Which would make your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 f
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(f.data, '"timeout_data":\s*"[^,"]+([^,"]+)+"')
AND ROWNUM<6;
```

*Note: you do not need to look for anything before or after the segment you are filtering for and you do not need to escape the double quotes.*